# Array in array, how do dump values here?

Tags: perl

I'm making a minimal case here, how should I dump the values of arrays inside array?

Multiple arrays, which contains a string value and a number, now I sort the array by second value, and read the value of the first field in order.

```
my @a = { "A" , 123 };
my @b = { "B" , 9 };

my @entries = ();
push @entries , \@a;
push @entries , \@b;

@entries = sort { $a[1] cmp $b[1] } @entries;
for (@entries)
{
        print @_[0] , "\n"; // should be "A\nB" after for loop
}
```

And what document should I view? Hmm... it's not like normal array in array, e.g syntax like `$a[0][0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't have an array of arrays there, you end up having an array of arrays of hashes because of the `{}` you use to construct `@a` and `@b`.
<sub>(BTW, `a` and `b` are poor choices as identifiers, especially given the use of scalar `$a` and `$b` in sort blocks – you don't want to confuse yourself with what you're dereferencing inside those sort blocks.)</sub>

If you fix that with:

```
my @a = ("A", 123);
my @b = ("B", 9);
```

Then you fix your sort to sort numerically (`cmp` is a string sort, `$a` and `$b` are array references):

```
sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } @entries;
```

And then change your `print` line to:

```
print $_->[0], "\n";
```

you should see the result you expect.

Add `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script, and make liberal use of the `Data::Dumper` module to debug it.

Comment: And `$a[1] cmp $b[1]` should be `$a->[1] <=> $b->[1]`

Comment: `@a` and `@b` doesn't interfere with sort, as you can see in this very case.

Comment: @ikegami: thanks, had fixed that in my test but forgot about it :) As for `@a`, indeed it's not a problem here, but best avoid them anyway (in my opinion).

Comment: They're best to avoid because they're generally poor names. Not for any non-existing relationship with `sort`. That's silly.